# Reference Request for Profiling High Performance Computing Codes

Tags: parallel-computing, reference-request

I write codes in Fortran and C for various matrix algorithms. However, when I profile my codes using VTune, I usually run into some terminology that I cannot fully appreciate. Is there a good resource for learning profiling from scratch to a fairly advanced level?

Although I am looking forward to profiling numerical codes, I don't think (I might be wrong) that profiling other codes is any different. **I want a tutorial on profiling and I would prefer an online (Free) PDF but wouldn't mind books or handbooks.**

I have tried reading VTune's handbook but thats like trying to learn chinese by reading a chinese language book.

Further, is VTune the best way to go? I really like a GUI and since I use Intel MKL, I figured it would be better than Valgrind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another common choice is to use PAPI http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/ or TAU http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Research/tau/home.php, Valgrind is great for finding memory errors.

Some slides from TACC:

http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/user-services/training/course-materials

http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=fc609b77-b727-4bff-81a4-d30caa4013d4&groupId=13601

Comment: Thanks for the great links. Can you also suggest a good tutorial in the form of PDF, book or otherwise to learn about profiling?

Comment: I don't have any books but I will ask around.

Comment: Okay after asking a few people, basically after you get past the easy things you have to know a lot about computer architecture.  We were recently tripped up on silly things like how fast it is to load a word on an Intel Chip (getting around hardware prefetching is not as easy as it sounds).

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in performance analysis of parallel codes I like the book:
[Scientific Parallel Computing, L. Ridgway Scott, Terry Clark, Babak Bagheri](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/069111935X).

Also, [here are some cool slides](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~ridg/newpsc/cp.pdf) used in a summer school course given (PASI. Valparaíso, Chile. January 2011) by one of the authors, the material is based on the book.

Answer (score 1):

I tool I have used extensively for profiling is [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) (in combination with the graphical interface [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)). Valgrind is a set of dynamic analysis tools: memory error detection, threading bug hunting and profiling.

Some references on Valgrind:

- [Valgrind 3.3 — Advanced Debugging and Profiling for GNU/Linux applications](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/valgrind/manual/)
- [Valgrind user manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual.html)

Unfortunately (depends on where you come from :-) ), valgrind doesn't run on Windows, only on Linux and Darwin based machines.